# Laptop lid close does not restart

Tags: suspend

When I close the lid, Elementary suspends the system. However, when I try to restart, it keeps flashing the screen with junk without ever recovering. The only option I have is to do a hard reset. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Have a look in your log via 'less /var/log/pm-suspend.log'. There might be some clues as to what driver is failing to resume from suspend.

Comment: There's no such file in /var/log. I should have clarified, though, that this was happening on a Live CD version. After installation on my hard disk (dual boot), I don't have the problem. But I have a new one. When waking back after suspend, only my external monitor works. My laptop monitor is blank/black and I receive an error message on the other screen that the system has encountered a problem detecting my laptop monitor. Only way to resolve is a reboot. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's better to ask a new question when you have another problem.

Answer (score 1):

As already said in the comment, using a live-system `suspend` won't resume. The cause is the missing swap partition (or file) with an appropriate filesystem (i.e. *not* `tmpfs`). If you insist on using a live-system, you may:

- config your live-system to never go to sleep and to not suspend when closing the lid, or
- add another writeable drive (USB, SDHC), format with e.g. `ext2` and create a swap file there.